# issue while Logging-In using Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, parse-platform, xcode6

I have made an app is which user can sign-in and sign-up using Parse.

But I am unable to to sign-in.

I copied the login-code from [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-login/iOS)

The code is:

```
 - (IBAction)didTapLogin:(id)sender
{
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:@"Rahul@gmail.com" password:@"mypass"
  block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
  if (user) {
    NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
 } else {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
 }
}];

}
```

I have set Up the Keys already in `App-Delegate.m`

I am getting following Error:

```
[Error]: invalid login parameters (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.2)
 Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 101.)" UserInfo=0x7feefa437070 {code=101, temporary=0, error=invalid login parameters, originalError=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)"}
```

What's the issue in code.As I have done nothing with it.

Comment: have you created a user on parse in "User" table?

Comment: Yes , I have a User Class ... and in That class there is user details also..like username ,password and email .... @AneeqAnwar

Comment: I have the same issue. Let me now when you find the answer

Comment: Today I can successfully login to Parse with the same code. I think yesterday Parse made some changes in their system.

Comment: @ayalcinkaya you are right..now i am able to sign in with same code..

Comment: Same Problem Here... Anyone has come up with a Solution?

Comment: it is the parse issue @HernanArber .. wait for some time it...if it works previously then it will work again... Have you get it working previously ?

Comment: Hi @RahulMishra, Nope... Stil Failing :-(

Comment: Did it work previously ?